# substitution cipher in c++

Tags: c++, random

I have generate a random text file

```
A B C D E F G H

T W G X Z R L N
```

I want to encode my message so that A = T , B = W , C = G and so on..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int
main ()
{
  string getmsg;

  ifstream openfile ("random.txt");

  if (openfile.is_open ()) {

    while (! openfile.eof ()) {
      getline (openfile,getmsg); //read from random.txt
      cout << getmsg << endl;
    }

  }
}
```

Am quite of stuck here.

eg. when i input the word "HAD" it will display "NTX" and by using the same random text file I can input "NTX" and give me back the "HAD"

Comment: Is this homework?  If so kindly use the `Homework` tag.

Comment: Does `random.txt` contain the mapping? Or does it contain the text you want to encode?

Comment: it contain the mapping as shown in the first 3 line of the question
the message to encode is user input.

Answer (score 3):

While others have pointed out Map, I would have used a simple array (`subs`), of size 26 (If there are only capital alphabets).

Initialize the array with 0s. Read all the chars and their mapping. Store it something like this `subs[char-'A'] = mapped_char`. I will leave the reading to you.

**EDIT**-
If you are ready to pay for extra memory usage, just make the size of `subs` as **123** (ASCII for `z` + 1).

This will also simplify the logic to `subs[char] = mapped_char`

Comment: how do i include small letter 'a' too

Comment: @user1526669:If you are ready to pay for extra memory usage, just make the size of `subs` as 123(ascii for z + 1). This will also simplify logic to `subs[char] = mapped_char`

Comment: but how does the program know that A will take the letter below ?

Comment: @user1526669:I thought you would be able to implement that. Read both the lines in a string each. Then iterate over the strings. So, `char` is the character from top string and `mapped_char` is character from bottom string.

Answer (score 2):

Since this feels like homework I'll give you guidance rather than a solution.

You want to create a [bijectional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) map between an input character and a corresponding character to output.

One solid way to do that is with a [Map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).  Create a Map that has as its key the input character e.g. 'A' and as its value the output character e.g. 'T'.

For each character that you read in from your file, use the Map to lookup the corresponding output character.

You will need to read input one character at a time (simplest), or read one line at a time (as you do now) and run through each line, character by character, to do the translation with the Map.

**Update**

To clarify a point in the comments, this is a bijectional function because there is exactly one encoded character for each original character.  If the text does not have to be decoded, a Map will do for the software representation of the function.  If decoding is needed, a Bimap is more appropriate.

[image: Injective Function]

*Injective Function*

[image: Bijective Function]

*Bijective Function*

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function

Comment: I dun get what you mean by bidirectional.
is it by using if else?

i cannot use character mapping because the random text file will not be the same and next time A might be D

Comment: Injectional should be sufficient here. If you need bijectional, `boost::bimap` is a better fit than `std::map`.

Comment: can give me some example how to do so?i am still lost

Comment: @moshbear: No, it's a bijection.  An injection means that there could be characters in the ENCODED set that are not mapped to from the ORIGINAL set.  There's a good picture of that here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function

Comment: To the downvoter: Why did you vote this down?  If something is wrong, please share what that is.

Comment: @user1526669: Does the file `random.txt` contain encrypted text to decode, or does it contain the mapping from plain to encrypted text?

Answer (score 0):

one way to do it is if you

take a look at `std::map<>`    (`map<char,char>` in your case)

using it you can setup a map of character pairs, then when you read one character from your file/buffer you look it up in the map and retrieve the corresponding character.

another, more verbose way, would be to have a switch statement

```
char ch; 
ch << openfile
switch(ch)
{
   case 'A': ch = 'T'; break;
...
}
cout << ch;
```

there are other ways as well, see if you can find one more involving an array.

Comment: by using this methodology will be A always be T?